# Entity не полное сохранение в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, context

Использую EF. У меня есть класс

```
public class Remont
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("KardOf")]
    public int RemontId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Диагностика", Prompt = "Предположительно что сломалось")]
    public List<Detal> Diagnost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Мастер", Prompt = "Кто выполнял ремонт")]
    public Master Master { get; set; }

    public virtual Kard KardOf { get; set; }
}
```

и второй класс

```
public class Detal//Деталь
{
    public int DetalId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Деталь", Prompt = "Тип детали")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Remont> Remonts { get; set; }
}
```

Когда выполняю пошаговую отладку, то данные все заполняются в контексте подключения в нужных сущностях (локально). Сохраняю. Но при чтении в другом методе БД, в таблице Remont есть указание на таблицу Kard, но указания в колонке Diagnost и Master имеют значение null. Почему? Что не так я делал и каких не хватает данных для полного добавления сущностей в БД, включая вложенные сущности?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Diagnostic(string[] detail)
{
    string teh = Request.Form["teh"];
    string kardId = Request.Form["kardId"];
    string master = Request.Form["master"];
    if ((teh != null) & (kardId != null) & (master != null))
    {
        ViewBag.teh = teh;
        ViewBag.kardId = kardId;
        Kard kard = db.Kards.Where(x => x.KardId.ToString() == kardId).FirstOrDefault();
        Master _master = db.Masters.Where(x => x.LastName == master).FirstOrDefault();
        if ((kard != null)&(_master != null))
        {
            Remont rem = new Remont();
            rem.Diagnost = new List<Detal>();
            //kard.Remont.
            foreach (var diag in detail)
            {
                Detal d = db.Detals.Where(x => x.DetalId.ToString() == diag).FirstOrDefault();
                if (d != null)
                {
                    rem.Diagnost.Add(d);
                    if (d.Remonts == null) 
                        d.Remonts = new List<Remont>();
                    d.Remonts.Add(rem);
                 }
            }

            kard.Remont = rem;
            kard.Remont.Master = _master;
            _master.RemontOf = new List<Remont>();
            _master.RemontOf.Add(kard.Remont);
            rem.KardOf = kard;

            db.Remonts.Add(kard.Remont);

            int i=db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Remont", new { teh = teh});
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Work");
}

public ActionResult Result()
{
    string teh = Request.QueryString["teh"];
    string kardId = Request.QueryString["kardId"];
    if ((teh != null) & (kardId != null))
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Результат ремонта";
        ViewBag.teh = teh;
        ViewBag.kardId = kardId;
        Remont result = db.Remonts.Where(x => x.KardOf.KardId.ToString() == kardId).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.master_lastname = result.Master.LastName;
```

[image: Это в методе Diagnostic]

[image: Это в методе Result]

Comment: Нужно установить many to many связь между этими сущностями. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что мне дало разъяснение, на примере. буду разбираться.